# How to allow an IIS App Pool to access a particular MS SQL database?

Tags: sql, iis, permissions

I am getting this error:
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\KBM2'.

I cannot seem to find where I would allow that user access to the database that I need to use for my application.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio express.

Can someone help a beginner?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use Network Authentication for the App Pool.

Comment: Do you mean you changed the application pool identity from `ApplicationPoolIdentity` to `NetworkService`?